# Unzip multiple files in a folder using ssis

Tags: ssis

I am currently using SSIS task to unzip a file .. but the file conatins multiple (subfolders)zip folders

i did this till now :

[image]

[image]

[image]

on successful execution the only parent file will get unzip not subfolders:(

say like these are my files(zip)

A.zip

having(B.zip,C.zip,D.zip)

and B.zip contains(a,b,c,d)... C.zip(a1,b1,c1,d1),...D.zip(a2,b2,c2,d2)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, you might want to try [Joost's solution](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/unzip-files-with-ssis.html), but tick the "Traverse Sub Folder" option in step 3